# Java serialization error for java 3d objects

Tags: java, serialization, java-3d

I have searched several posts but I can't get my program working.
So here is the problem ----
I have a class which display a colorcube and a save button, the save button is for save the java3d object (here colorcube) to a object file for later use.

The object file was created but It seems empty except 2-3 lines.
Please have a look ---

```
public class Rotation extends Applet implements ActionListener {

//---- Attribute -----------------------
private SimpleUniverse universe;
private Canvas3D canvas3D;
private static Frame frame;
BranchGroup szene = new BranchGroup(); 
TransformGroup objDreh = new TransformGroup();
ColorCube cube = new ColorCube(0.4);

public Rotation() 
{}

public void init() {
setLayout(new BorderLayout());
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JButton btn = new JButton("Save");
btn.addActionListener(this);
panel.add(btn);
GraphicsConfiguration config = SimpleUniverse.getPreferredConfiguration();
canvas3D = new Canvas3D(config);
add(canvas3D, BorderLayout.CENTER);
add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
szene = macheSzene();
szene.compile();
universe = new SimpleUniverse(canvas3D);
universe.getViewingPlatform().setNominalViewingTransform();
universe.addBranchGraph(szene);
}

/**
 * Erstellt den Szenegraphen
 * 
 * @return BranchGroup
 */
public BranchGroup macheSzene() {
BranchGroup objWurzel = new BranchGroup();
// Transformation, 2 Rotationen:
Transform3D drehung = new Transform3D();
Transform3D drehung2 = new Transform3D();
drehung.rotX(Math.PI / 4.0d);
drehung2.rotY(Math.PI / 5.0d);
drehung.mul(drehung2);
objDreh = new TransformGroup(drehung);
TransformGroup spin = new TransformGroup();
spin.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
spin.addChild(cube);
objDreh.addChild(spin);
objWurzel.addChild(objDreh);

// Drehung
Alpha spinAlpha = new Alpha(-1, 5000);
RotationInterpolator dreher = new RotationInterpolator(spinAlpha, spin);
BoundingSphere zone = new BoundingSphere();
dreher.setSchedulingBounds(zone);
spin.addChild(dreher);

return objWurzel;
}

/**
* gibt speicher frei
*/
public void destroy() {
universe.removeAllLocales();
}


@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
    try {
        writeIntoFile();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Rotation.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}

public void writeIntoFile() throws FileNotFoundException
{
    //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    SerializeObject obj = new SerializeObject(cube);
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("e://j3dObjects.xml");
        try {
            ObjectOutputStream sout = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
            sout.writeObject(obj);
            sout.close();
        } catch (Exception err)
            { err.printStackTrace(); }
    }  catch(Exception err)
    { err.printStackTrace(); }     
}




public static void main(String[] args) {
frame = new MainFrame(new Rotation(), 500, 500);
frame.setTitle("Rotation");
}

}
```

and the serializable class-------

```
public class SerializeObject extends ColorCube implements Serializable {

ColorCube cb;


SerializeObject(ColorCube brn)
{
    this.cb = brn;
}   
}
```

Please have a look, and let me know where I'm doing wrong.
And one more thing is it possible to write a transformgroup into object file?
Thanks.

Comment: First of all, learn, please, how to properly format your code. It is unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

To Serialize an object, all its fields must be serializable (here `Colorcube`) or they should be declared `transient`. 
Please make sure that `ColorCube` is serializable (ie. it implements the `Serializable` interface) to get your code working.

Answer (score 0):

When Serizlizing an object you have to decide what to do with each attribute. Here there are two main options:

1) You serialize it: it this attribute's class implements serializable (or it is a primitive type) it is ok, else you have to code how to serialize it (implementing serializable).

2) Not to serialize this attribute, if you do not want to serialize this attribute because it is a temporal caches or whatever (it does not represent the state of this object) you can mark it as `transient` and this attribute will not be serialized. In this case you do not have to worry about how to serialize this attribute and its class does not have to implement serializable.